# Error compiling OpenCV for raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspberry Pi4 and OpenCV to make a basic facial recognition application.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-opencv/) but am getting the same error when compiling OpenCV at 53%, as shown below:

`Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.so`

Then it prints:

`libopencv_calib3d.so.4.8.0] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4619: modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib                                                                             3d.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2`

I've tried restarting the tutorial and used both
`make` and `make -j$(nproc)` when compiling but both get stuck at this one point.

Comment: This one worked for me, Here is link: https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/. You don't do cmake and make. It is better for Bookworm.

Comment: Hey @toyota Supra, I tried that link and when I enter 'sudo apt install -y ./opencv_64.deb' Im hit with more errors saying 'Note, selecting 'opencv:arm64' instead of './opencv_64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.' Any help woul be appreciated as its college related

Comment: I still have problem...sudo apt install python3-opencv-contrib using Bookworm

Comment: The link is awaiting Cross-Compiler Toolchain for Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. Be patient.